# Why I got : The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'List<int>'?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, for-loop, display

I'm new with flutter I want to display the same list for 20 times but I always got this error : **The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'List'**

this is my code :

```
List<int> _getRandomBytes(int nboucle) {
      for (int i = 1; i < nboucle; i++) {
    List<int> listbytes = [
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XFF,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
      0XAB,
      0XFF,
      0XFF,
      0XFF,
      0XCA,
    ];
       return listbytes;
      }

  
   

  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How do you call _getRandomBytes?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran _getRandomBytes(20)

Answer (score 1):

[doc:](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=body_might_complete_normally#body_might_complete_normally)

> The analyzer produces this diagnostic when a method or function has a
> return type that’s potentially non-nullable but would implicitly
> return null if control reached the end of the function.

simple defenition:
Your declare `non-null` function, which is `List<int>`. but you put the return inside the loop.

it causes your function to probably return null outside the loop.
try this:

```
List<int> _getRandomBytes(int nboucle) {
    List<int> listbytes=[];
    for (int i = 1; i < nboucle; i++) {
      listbytes = [
        0XFF,
        0XCA,
        ....
      ];
    }
    return listbytes;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you set the return inside the `for loop`,
here what it should be.

```
List<int> _getRandomBytes(int nboucle) {
late List<int> listbytes;
for (int i = 1; i < nboucle; i++) {
  listbytes = [
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XAB,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XAB,
    0XFF,
    0XFF,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XAB,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XAB,
    0XFF,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
    0XAB,
    0XFF,
    0XFF,
    0XFF,
    0XCA,
  ];
}
return listbytes;
```

}

Comment: this will throw `Undefined name 'listbytes'.` because you are calling listbytes outside the for loop, but you are declaring it inside the loop

Comment: @Gwhyyy thank you this work for me. Just one other question : if I want to display the same list for 20 times is calling _getRandomBytes(20) true !!!

Comment: then you can loop over that function 20 times if you want to display it 20 times

Comment: @Gwhyyy I looped : **for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)**  But the list still displayes only for 1 time

Comment: Please include what did you exactly did inside the for loop, I suppose that you just runned the method 20 times, I mean it's true but you should store the returns list in a global list that holds all of them, like: List globalList = []; for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {globalList.addAll(_getRandomBytes() )}